# Return Data From Function F#

Tags: f#

I'm new to F#. I have a Function that does some database operation. I am struggling returning result.

```
let funcA () = 
 let funcB () = 
    // do some database operation and returns seq of records
 let funcC () = 
    // do some other database operation returns nothing
 let result = funcB ()
 funcC ()
```

How can I return `result` from `funcA`? I need to execute `funcB` before `funcC`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last line of the function should be your return value.  In your case you don't necessarily need to nest functions here, but we can leave it as is.  Also, it's important to note that F# is an eagerly-evaluated language by default, so if you define your functions without any parameters they will actually be evaluated up front (and will not change with future executions).  If you do not actually require any paramters for your function, then provide a `unit` value as your parameter.

`let funcA () = // Function defintion`

instead of

`let funcA = // Function definition`

```
let funcA () = 
 let funcB () = 
     // Perform database operation
 let funcC () = 
     // Perform some side-effect, returns ()

 let result = funcB ()
 funcC ()

 result // This will be your return value

let a = funcA () // Example usage
```

Comment: Is there no way to return `result` after executing `funcC`?

Comment: See my edit, the key is that the last line is your return value.  So by just putting `result` at the end it will be returned instead of the result of `funcC ()`

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works fine, but it is not very fsharp-y

If your funcC may only be executed after funcB, this can be made more explicit by using the result type of funcB as input to funcC. Or even better, use the railway pattern:

```
let funcA () =
  let funcB () : Result<Seq<Foo>, string> =
    // perform database operation, return Ok <| sequence of Foo if successful
    // otherwise Error <| "sql failed"

  let funcC x =
    // perforn some side effect
    x //return input
  funcB ()
  |> Result.map funcC
```

( [See Scott Wlaschins excellent posts about railway oriented programming](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/) )